# How to import 10 gb sql file in mysql quickly?

Tags: mysql, database, magento, large-files

I have 10 gb sql file and I am importing this file using command line :

mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql

However, it's taking too much time. Is there any other option or tool to import this file quickly?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using MySQL big dump, it's worked for me in the past with databases around that size:

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

> Staggered import of large and very large MySQL Dumps (like phpMyAdmin
>   dumps) even through the web servers with hard runtime limit and those
>   in safe mode. The script imports only a small part of the huge dump
>   and restarts itself. The next session starts where the last was
>   stopped.